# JApplet issue in IE 10

Tags: java, internet-explorer, applet, japplet

I have a JApplet in a frame.  When I launch the pop up  in IE 10, 
applet is becoming a white screen. If I click 2 to 3 times on frame, it is again coming properly .

Why is the applet coming up as white screen when launching the pop up?

Comment: could you post the running code of the applet? Have you tested it with other browsers or just with IE?

Comment: What is the URL of the applet?

Answer (score 0):

As workaround I use

> setTimeout()

in javascript to check Java plugin installed or not.
And really often it works from the second time.